# Number of complex numbers such that $z^{80} = 1$ and other properties

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $$A = \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re z > 0, \Im z < 0, z^{80} = 1 \right \}$$
>
> Then, the number of elements in $A$ is $19$, $20$, $21$, or $22$?

I just started studying complex numbers and I've come across this question. I really don't know how to approach it. Do you think it's solvable with basic techniques?

I think we state the problem as finding the number of roots $r$ of the polynomial $z^{80}-1$ such that $r$ is in the fourth quadrant of the complex plane. I also recall that if $z$ is a root, then $\overline{z}$ is one too? That restricts the answers to the even ones, so $20$ or $22$, right?

Comment: Note that when we have real roots than we may have an odd number of roots - such as in the case of $z^3=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: To find all the solutions of $z^{80}=1$ write $z$
is polar form
$$
z=rcis(\theta)
$$

then we have 
$$
r^{80}cis(80\theta)=1=1cis(0)
$$

and so $r=\sqrt[80]{1}=1$ and $80\theta=2\pi k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
The solutions are 
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi k}{40};\, k=0,1,...,79
$$

Now find which of them satisfies the rest of the conditions

Comment: I believe you're saying what I think you are saying but I can't actually follow what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Note that the roots of unity of order n
  form a regular n-sided polygon inscribed in the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

$$A= \{ e^{\frac{2 k\pi i}{80}} : k \in \mathbb{Z}, 60 < k < 80\}$$ hence the answer is 19.